# XML Parsing using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, парсер

Имею xml файл, который содержит теги
Вот исходнй xml:

```
<MOTree>
    <MO className="BTS">
        <p name='BSC_NUM'>xxyy</p>
        <p name="frequencyBandInUse">1</p>
        <p name="gprsMsTxPwrMaxCCH1x00">0</p>
        <p name="minMsTxPower">15</p>
        <p name="msTxPwrMaxCCH1x00">0</p>
        <p name="msTxPwrMaxGSM1x00">0</p>
        <p name="insiteGateway">0</p>
        <p name="name">xxx_yyy_zzz</p>
        <p name="adaptiveLaAlgorithm">0</p>
        <p name="adminState">3</p>
    </MO>
    <MO className="BTS">
        <p name="maioOffset">0</p>
        <p name="maioStep">1</p>
        <p name="masterBcf">1</p>
        <p name="maxGPRSCapacity">100</p>
        <p name="maxNumberOfRepetition">15</p>
        <p name="maxNumberRetransmission">2</p>
        <p name="maxQueueLength">50</p>
        <p name="maxTimeLimitDirectedRetry">7</p>
    </MO>
</MOTree>
```

Необходимо получить общий список имен тегов

с аттрибутом name.

Comment: И с чем вы хотите сделать это? каким языком программирования ?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan очевидно, C#.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Я использую C#.

Comment: а когда значения совпадают, то что должно попасть в результирующую "таблицу"?

Comment: Мне необходимо привязаться к имени тега "p name=1". В данном случае значение внутри тега <p name="1">1</p> не играет ни какой роли.

Comment: окей, а если имя совпадает?

Comment: Мне как раз и необходимо получить список всех имен по всем тегам.

Comment: а в вопросе написано, что нужна какая-то таблица

Comment: Исправил. Уточнил вопрос.

Comment: вам нужно изменить структуру .xml или просто получить список всех `P` с аттрибутом `name` внутри `mo`?

Comment: У меня в xml файле содержатся разделы <MO> с разным колличеством тегов <p>. Мне необходимо получить полный список всех P с аттрибутом name внутри mo.

Comment: И в чём вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в дополнительном классе <MOTree>. Если все делаю по вашему примеру, тогда работает, но при наличие только одного класса <MO>. А если класс в классе, тогда возвращает пусто.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте вместо устаревшего `XmlDocument` используем Linq2Xml.

Это делается, по сути, одной строкой методом [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.union(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var xml1 = XElement.Load("test1.txt");
var xml2 = XElement.Load("test2.txt");

var union = xml1.Elements("p").Union(xml2.Elements("p"), new XElementComparer())
    //.OrderBy(elem => elem.Attribute("name").Value)
    ;

var xml = new XElement("MO", union);
```

Раскомментировать строку, если нужен отсортированный порядок.

Дополнительно нам нужен класс, реализующий [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
class XElementComparer : IEqualityComparer<XElement>
{
    public bool Equals(XElement x, XElement y)
    {
        return x.Attribute("name").Value == y.Attribute("name").Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(XElement obj)
    {
        return (int)obj.Attribute("name");
        //return obj.Attribute("name").Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Если в атрибуте `name` могут быть не целочисленные значения, то использовать закомментированную строку.

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. С отдельными файлами работает отлично. Только у меня теги находятся в одном xml.

Comment: @Vitaliy - просто укажите к ним нужные пути (`Elements("...").Elements("...")`).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Vitaliy значит проблема решена?

Comment: Не совсем. Обнаружил, что у моего исходника структура файла следующая: <MOTree>
 <MO>
  <p name="1">1</p>
  <p name="2">2</p>
  <p name="3">3</p>
  <p name="5">5</p>
  <p name="7">7</p>
  <p name="8">8</p>
 </MO>
 <MO>
  <p name="1">1</p>
  <p name="2">2</p>
  <p name="4">4</p>
  <p name="5">5</p>
  <p name="6">6</p>
  <p name="8">8</p>
 </MO>
</MOTree>

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось на первом этапе.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var xml1 = XElement.Load("test1_1.txt");
                var xml2 = XElement.Load("test2_1.txt");
                var union = xml1.Descendants("p").Union(xml2.Descendants("p"), new XElementComparer());
                var xml = new XElement("MO", union);
                Console.WriteLine(xml);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Теперь необходимо выполнить все тоже самое, но только в пределах одного xml  файла.